# TVS diode vs capacitor

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, diodes, tvs

I've gone through this [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/580462/difference-between-esd-and-tvs-diode) which is a similar question.

In some places, capacitors are also used for ESD purposes.

In some places, along with capacitors, TVS diodes (or ESD diodes, not sure which term is correct) are used.

Can someone tell me where TVS diodes should be used and where capacitors should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that ESD diodes have a much lower capacitance; this is often a feature that is advertized.

If you have slow/low-frequency signals, you can afford to put a capacitor directly on the signal line; slowed-down signal edges do not hurt, and will even be useful to prevent EMI.

But if you have high-speed signals, then a capacitor would reduce signal quality too much. So you need a diode to shunt the ESD current into the power supply rails, where it can be eaten by the decoupling capacitor(s).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, TVS diodes and ESD diodes are the same, right?

Comment: Not really; transient voltage events usually have lower voltage but more energy than ESD events. The datasheets tell you what they are tested against.

Comment: Thank you! So, what parameter is the main difference between the TVS diode and the ESD diode?

Comment: ESD is a subset of possible Transient Voltage events that need Suppressors. There's also EFT, cable discharge event, lightning induced surge, inrush, various load switching or dumping, and still other transients.  Some TVSs (including non-diode types) are more suitable for some of these transients than others, and some are more suitable for certain applications than others. @Newbie , you may find this useful to your present activities: https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slva233a/slva233a.pdf?ts=1679891165743